# Most confusing plots of sinus signal with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, signals

I have "discovered" the most confusing thing while plotting sinus signal with python. We agree, the formula for a sinus signal is (source wiki: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_sinuso%C3%AFdal):
y = sin(2 * pi * f * t + phi),
with t the time, f the frequency, and phi the phase difference.

Now, I was trying to plot sinus signals with different frequencies, e.g. f = 10e6 Hz, f = 10 Hz, but the plot is the same for both frequencies !!! What am I doing wrong ?
Here is my code:

```
    # time span of the measured signals
t = np.linspace(0,100,1000) # start, stop, number

# Generate some sinus signal data
signal1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10  * t)
signal2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10e6 * t)

# Plot the signals
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, signal1, c='r', label ='S1')
plt.plot(t, signal2, c='b', label ='S2' )
plt.ylabel('Signal intensity')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's not the same, but the differences are indistinguishable visually. You could separately plot `signal1 - signal2` to visualize the difference, for example.

Comment: Your time increments are about 0.1001s (i.e. 100 / 1000+1, from the linspace call). So 1 "tick" of time is very slightly more than 1 whole cycle of a 10 Hz wave, or very slightly more than a million whole cycles of a 10e6 Hz wave. Almost all of the "extra" oscillation of the 10e6 Hz wave is lost between ticks - the time resolution is very low relative to the frequence of the waves.

Comment: Related: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10418 Particularly, the 4th image in that answer explains what is going on here. Your plot reflects the blue "wave" there that comes from a low sampling frequency, rather than the green wave which is the actual underlying signal.